# Will scrapy scrape cached webpages or skip them?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am scraping a website with scrapy with the following settings:

```
HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
HTTPCACHE_DIR = f"{DATA_PATH}/saved_html"
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = "scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage"
```

My understanding of this setting is that scrapy will see a url, and if it is already cached on my local machine, it will scrape the cache instead of pinging the actual website. But scrapy seems to instead just skip over cached webpages, i.e. not scraping them and not putting the items in a database, and just extracting items from pages it has not seen. Is this intended? If not, what could be wrong? Do I need to use a certain DownloaderMiddleware? Right now, the only DownloaderMiddleware I am using is an empty, standard one.

Comment: You need to disable the dupfilter

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py set the DUPEFILTER_CLASS setting to 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'.

You can also set the `dont_filter` parameter in your Request objects to `True` which will have the same effect.

From [scrapy docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class):

> DUPEFILTER_CLASS
> Default: 'scrapy.dupefilters.RFPDupeFilter'
>
> The class used to detect and filter duplicate requests.
>
> The default (RFPDupeFilter) filters based on the REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_CLASS setting.
>
> You can disable filtering of duplicate requests by setting DUPEFILTER_CLASS to 'scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter'. Be very careful about this however, because you can get into crawling loops. It’s usually a better idea to set the dont_filter parameter to True on the specific Request that should not be filtered.

Comment: Isn't this something else? It uses fingerprinting, i.e. two URLs pointing to the same source should not be repeated. But if I tell scrapy to go to a specific URL in my crawling, I want it to scrape it, either from live if not cached or from cached if it is cached. As of right now, it seems scrapy does not process items if the source is from cached.

Comment: I don't know maybe I misunderstood your question.  Create a [mre] if this doesn't solve your issue. @jgklsdjfgkldsfaSDF